# Material - no provider for DateAdapter in lazily loaded third party module

Tags: angular

In my applicaiton I'm using a custom DateAdapter based on dayJs.

This is the definition of the module that provides it:

```js
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_DAYJS_DATE_FORMATS },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: DayJsDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]}
  ],
})
export class MatDayjsDateModule {}
```

which is imported like this in my application bootstrap module:

```js
const MODULES_TO_EXPORT = [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDayjsDateModule,
];

const formats = { parse: { ... }, display: { ... } }

@NgModule({
    imports: [...MODULES_TO_EXPORT],
    declarations: [ ],
    providers: [{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'it-IT' }, { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: formats }]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This works without issues for eager and lazy modules, as long as they are defined in the application, but when i try to transform a lazy module into a library and load it into the application like this:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/pages/dashboard", pathMatch: "full" },
    {
        path: "pages", component: PagesComponent, children:
            [
                ...
                { path: "adm", loadChildren: () => import('@template/admin-module').then(m => m.AdmModule) },
            ]
    }
];
```

As soon as i navigate to a component declared by that module that has Date Inputs i receive the usual `No provider found for DateAdapter`. I have no problems with any other service injections inside this kind of modules, only with the DateAdapter.

Any idea?
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

with a lazy-loaded module, you need to register the provider at the component level to get a new instance of the service, and this is a requirement for DateAdapter.

this is an example:

```
@Component({
 /* . . . */
 providers: [
   { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_DAYJS_DATE_FORMATS },
   { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: DayJsDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]}
 ]
})
```

I've created a working example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b14noa?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.html) with a custom Format and a custom locale

Comment: This is not the case as lazy loaded module inherits the injector from the root application.

The actual problem was that i was importing and redefining MAT_DATE_FORMATS for every lazy module and for some reason when the external module was loaded my injector had many instances of MAT_DATE_FORMATS and resolved to the empty object constant NOT_FOUND_CHECK_ONLY_ELEMENT_INJECTOR, which was causing all of my issues.

Moving the definition of MAT_DATE_FORMATS only in the providers of my bootstrap module did the trick. 

I cannot mark your answer as resolving, but you helped me figure it out